# How can override custom class-li element inside another class-li?

Tags: css, html

i starting with HTML5 and CSS3 and i'm stuck in this situation:

This is my HTML and CSS code so far:

```css
.custom-list ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.custom-list li {
  display: block;
}

.custom-list li::before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}

.custom-list-2 ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.custom-list-2 li::before {
  content: "# " counter(elementcounter) ". ";
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.custom-list-3 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.custom-list-3 li::before {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-list">
  <div class="custom-list-3">
    <ul>
      <li>TEST 1</li>
      <li>TEST 2</li>
      <li>TEST 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

My result is this:

[image]

And this is what i want:

[image]

How can this done?

Update: 1

[image]

this is the problem here... i need the 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 just to disappear and just us the current `<ul></ul>` provide

Update 2

With @sol solution almost works!

[image]

What i need now is make disappear the point before the 1.5 text..

Comment: Doesn't a `<ul>` have regular bullet points by default? Why do you need this styling at all? What are you trying to achieve that a regular `<ul>` doesn't provide?

Comment: Delete every line of CSS...

Comment: Where did you get this CSS? It seems like you don't understand what it's doing, so I would consider starting all over again with no CSS and then add only what you need to get the desired effect.

Comment: Seriously though, just delete all CSS lines you have and you'll get what you wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/41/

Comment: @csmckelvey i need this because my list is very particular... the css is work just fine in other case what i need

Comment: If you have a particular case, then you need to show us that case. We can't answer when we don't have all the information.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio this is true...but i need all my css..and i need this to work

Comment: Is the text 1,2,3 not supposed in the html? and do you have any other or nested ul/ol lists?

Comment: @csmckelvey update the problem...can you understand?

Comment: @VXp yes... allowed, but my html is not a problem here...just css., i guess

Comment: @VXp  boss request :(

Comment: Are you serious? @VXp is right. Just remove the class name from the HTML...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you still want to keep the styles for `.custom-list-3` for other purposes, you can override it where you need by adding the following:

```
.custom-list li {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: disc;
}

.custom-list-3 li::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```css
.custom-list ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.custom-list li {
  display: block;
}

.custom-list li::before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}

.custom-list-2 ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.custom-list-2 li::before {
  content: "# " counter(elementcounter) ". ";
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.custom-list-3 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.custom-list-3 li::before {
  list-style-type: circle;
}

.custom-list li {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: disc;
}

.custom-list-3 li::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-list">
  <div class="custom-list-3">
    <ul>
      <li>TEST 1</li>
      <li>TEST 2</li>
      <li>TEST 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sol  in the last comentary you're right..i need the counters for a reason... sorry can express soo good in english...this solution almost work how i want..but not all

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: OK...i solve my problem with this code from  @sol but i modify like this:  .custom-list-3 li {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
  }
  
.custom-list-3 li::before {
    content: '';
  }